# lists - can you have two styles in the same list?

Tags: css, styles, html-lists

A website I'm working on has a navigation bar at the top and is created using an unordered list. I need to add a Facebook button to be inline with the rest of the navigation bar but I want it to not take on the same CSS styling properties as the navigation bar (ie: the CSS properties pertaining to that particular list). Is there a way to write the code so that I can have the Facebook button inline with the navigation bar but have a different style applied to it?

Thanks!

Comment: use [class selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Class_selectors)

Comment: @TI- can you provide an example to elaborate what you mean? I saw somewhere where you can add different class selectors to differentiate and apply several styles but where do you place it within a list if it's taking it's styles from the list CSS properties?

Comment: @TI - nevermind I think JakeGould explained it for me. Thanks for your help too!

Comment: very simple example but see http://jsfiddle.net/K2HFp/

Comment: thanks TI for the example.

Comment: sorry misunderstood i agree with woolm110 see http://jsfiddle.net/K2HFp/1/

Answer (score 4):

You should refrain from using !important, it's bad practice, while it works to override inherited styles, the same can be achieved by tiering your css structure to create more powerful css, read this article into how you can achieve the same without having to use the !important rule.

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/

To style the facebook button differently, simple give it an id (e.g. #facebook) and use that to give it specific styles

```
li#facebook {
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 0;
}
```

This will then apply these styles only to the element that has the ID of facebook

Comment: It should only be used when absolutely necessary and shouldn't be used to cut corners or overcome impracticalities, if the same result can be achieved in a different way then that way should be used..

Comment: Agree with woolm110, `!important` should be used only when absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set separate styles for the Facebook element that will override the parent CSS with the `!important` declaration. [This site](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/) offers a good explanation.

Without your CSS it’s hard to explain how to use it, but let’s make up an example. Like this is your parent CSS styling for a specific list (`li`) element:

```
li {
  padding: 20px;
  margin 0 5px 0 5px;
  background-color: #ffc;
}
```

So if you want the Facebook element to not inherit the `padding` or `background-color`, set a class called `#facebook` and then set as follows:

```
li#facebook {
  padding: 0 !important;
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

That should ensure that the `#facebook` element gets a 0 `padding` and the `background-color` is set to transparent.

But like I said, hard to give a solid answer without your CSS so you should experiment with `!important` in your own setup to get the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

How about going against the grain?

For instance - float all li's right, making the facebook link the first menu item.
Then, you can employ the use of :first-child to style up the facebook menu item and no identifier is required for the use of CSS any of the elements?

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

ul {
    float:right;
    list-style:none;
}
li {
    float:right;
    margin:0 0 0 20px;
}
li a {
    float:right;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
}
li:first-child a {
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#f00;
}
```

Here's an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/seemly/wMWHc/